# zcount syntax for redis-py

Tags: python, redis

What's the syntax for *exclusive* `min` and `max` arguments for redis `zcount` command in python (redis-py)? It's not alluded to in the [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Would it be:

```
minimum = time.time() - 2000
maximum = time.time()
my_server.zadd(sorted_set, '('+str(minimum), maximum)
```

Comment: You're correct. Just prefix any limit with a  `(`  to use an exclusive limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `sys.float_info.epsilon`? This is the smallest comparable difference between two numbers:

```
minimum = time.time() - 2000
maximum = time.time()
my_server.zadd(sorted_set, minimum + sys.float_info.epsilon, maximum)
```

Or, with `-` for maximum:

```
minimum = time.time() - 2000
maximum = time.time()
my_server.zadd(sorted_set, minimum, maximum - sys.float_info.epsilon)
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [unit tests](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/eae07e76b6524e6772be60169549766e7826419a/tests/test_commands.py) gives some examples:

```
def test_zcount(self, r):
    r.zadd('a', a1=1, a2=2, a3=3)
    assert r.zcount('a', '-inf', '+inf') == 3
    assert r.zcount('a', 1, 2) == 2
    assert r.zcount('a', 10, 20) == 0
```

This can help…